# Why doesn't Date.today work on Ruby console (irb)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb

In irb I am trying Date.today and it fails.

I was originally trying to do:

```
Date.today.strftime "%b %d, '%y"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How does it fail? Does it fail like this?

```
phrogz$ irb
> Date.today
NameError: uninitialized constant Object::Date
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

> require 'date'
#=> true

> Date.today
#=> #<Date: 2010-12-05 (4911071/2,0,2299161)>
```

If so, there's your answer. (If not, then [provide more details](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) and we'll move forward from there.)

Comment: Why does most ruby question date back 10 years ?

Comment: @PeterMoore Maybe because Ruby on Rails got super popular at the time, and perhaps has become less popular since?